# Get Simple Remote Akka Application Running

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to set up a simple server/client akka (using Akka 2.0.3) application, but it failed to connect. Beforehand here is the basic code:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props

class Server extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case s: String => println("Got " + s)
  }
}

val serverSystem = ActorSystem("server", ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
      transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
      netty {
        hostname = "localhost"
        port = 5678
      }
    }
  }
""")))

val server = serverSystem.actorOf(Props[Server], name = "server")
Thread.sleep(500)
println("started")
Thread.sleep(500)

val clientSystem = ActorSystem("client", ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
  }
""")))
val remoteServer = clientSystem.actorFor("akka://server@XXX:5678/user/server")

remoteServer ! "HEY"

Thread.sleep(3000)
clientSystem.shutdown
serverSystem.shutdown
```

I know that the configurations should be placed in external files.
If you replace `XXX` with `localhost` it works:

```
started
Got HEY
```

But if I used my external (resolved) IP (PC behind home router) for `XXX` the `HEY` message never arrives. I thought it is due to some firewall problem and forwarded the related TCP and UDP ports at my router and also opened/allowed them at my Windows firewall. So after that the following code worked (also `XXX` replaced with my external IP). A started `ServerTest` can be connected by a `ClientTest`:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
object ServerTest extends App {
  println("START server")
  val ss = new ServerSocket(5678)
  val s = ss.accept()
  println(s)
  println("END")
}

import java.net.Socket
object ClientTest extends App {
  println("START client")
  val s = new Socket("XXX", 5678)
  println(s)
  println("END")
}
```

So it´s not a port/firewall problem, isn´t it?! So where is the problem???

Comment: Akka Remoting is not dealing with firewalls or NAT: http://akka.io/faq/

Comment: @Viktor Although it´s answers my question, I am still wondering why the socket version is capable and akka is not.

Comment: @Viktor Would you mind to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?!

Comment: Btw, you need to put an externally reachable hostname or IP as "hostname" in your config. "localhost" is not an externally reachable address.

Comment: see also: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/1552#/activity/ticket:

Comment: reasons why: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/fCD6Nvz9ybg/RnAWHrpAl0YJ

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` usually means `127.0.0.1`, which is only one of the possibly many interfaces (cards) in a computer. The server binding to localhost won't receive connections connecting to the other interfaces (including the one with the external address).

You should either specify the external address in the server, or `0.0.0.0` which means "bind to all interfaces".

Comment: Binding the server to the external address fails with `Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /84.187.XXX.XXX:5678`, so I tried your `0.0.0.0` which binds but doesn´t receive the `HEY`-message. The same with `192.168.2.101`, the IP-address of my LAN-interface(card) which is connected to the router. So any new thoughts?

Comment: By the way. `0.0.0.0` makes sense compared to `println(new ServerSocket(5678))` which yields `ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=5678]`.