# Akka peer behind a firewall

Tags: scala, networking, akka

As far as I can see there is no way to run Akka remote tcp client placed behind a firewall, because every Akka peer has to have a tcp server socket to be able to receive messages. Am I right?

I need to create a pure tcp client with Akka that would be able to connect to a remote server and receive responses from it but unable to receive incoming connections.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542496/get-simple-remote-akka-application-running

Comment: There is no answer to my question in that post. But it seems that every peer need to be a server to be able to receive messages.

Comment: I am not sure whether I fully understand your question but if the main problem is the firewall perhaps you could try ssh tunnelling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. All akka nodes should be able to receive incoming requests.
Typically response is posted into a akka queue. 
I doubt if it can happen without an incoming connection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to go through a proxy server.

In order to do that you need to pass the httpProxy and httpPort flag to the JVM. 
You can do that with "-J" switch or passing in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable