# Akka-remote over the Internet

Tags: scala, akka, p2p, nat

I'm writing [distributed BBS software](https://github.com/windymelt/p2p2ch/) using Akka 2.2.3 as remote message passing in Scala.

Then, I've found some problem in networking over the Internet through NAT: Akka doesn't recognize external IP address, AFAIK because it uses `socket.bind`.

Next, I thought that I can specify 0.0.0.0 as `akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname` in order to adopt all interfaces and addresses to listen connections from the Internet side.

Here is the problem -- Akka uses 0.0.0.0 as its own IP address, and generates `ActorRef` like this: `akka.tcp://system@0.0.0.0/user/foo`.

Other nodes cannot refer the node using this `ActorRef` over the Internet.
What should I do for connecting nodes over the Internet? Can't I use Akka over NAT?

Comment: Akka does not support NAT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542496/get-simple-remote-akka-application-running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Akka remoting does not support NAT, which is intentional since its purpose is just to enable clustering (i. e. symmetrical communication between a tightly controlled set of nodes). There are several protocols that have been devised for Internet-wide use, e. g. HTTP/REST (see Spray which is becoming Akka HTTP) or bare TCP using Akka IO.

Comment: Thank you. I consider using of Spray.

Comment: Has the situation changed now? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/remoting.html#Akka_behind_NAT_or_in_a_Docker_container

Comment: The intention has not been changed: Akka remote is not meant to be used across the Internet in general, even though it might technically work now.